# jQuery Mobile - How to link a html page which has some ajax in it within another html page

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an application developed using phoneGap and jQuery Mobile. On the first page there is a  navigation bar that the user clicks to navigate to a page which also has some ajax calls to get JSON feeds from a server. I am doing the following,

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="sites.html" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active">My</a></li>
  <li><a href="profile.html" data-icon="gear">Recent</a></li>
</ul>
```

But the page is not loading. But if I open the page directly it works nicely. My ajax calls are in the document.ready() event.

What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with phone gap, but jQuery Mobile will automatically turn internal links into ajax calls. You shouldn't have to do anything with your `document.ready()`.

[jQuery Mobile Documentation - Page Links](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-links.html)

---

In jQuery Mobile, the `document.ready()` only fires when the initial page loads. Also, because jQuery Mobile only pulls in content when it loads a fresh page, nothing in the header is executed. In order to simulate the effect of `document.ready()` on other pages, do the following:

```
$('#aboutPage').live('pagecreate',function(event){
alert('This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!');
// Insert the calls that were in the document.ready() here.
});
```

[jQuery Mobile Documentation - Page Scrpting](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

Comment: Sorry, I think I have not explained my issue correctly. What I am doing inside my document.ready() function is some GET calls to a server to get some feeds. What I am experiencing is I cannot get those calls working when I navigate though the links to those pages.

Comment: If it worked, I would greatly appreciate if you "Accepted" my answer by clicking on the check mark near the my answer. Thanks!